# Binary representation of a number is palindrome or not?

Tags: code-golf, binary, palindrome

Write a full program  to find whether the binary representation of a number is palindrome or not?

```
Sample Input
5

Sample Output
YES
```

Print `YES` if binary representation is palindrome and `NO` otherwise.

Comment: What should be the output when it's _not_ a palindrome?

Comment: @dogbert It should be 'NO' without the quotes.

Comment: How do you know it's a palindrome? Because the values from the first nonzero to the end of the "string" are palindromic? This smells really bad to me, as a challenge.

Comment: Much as I <3 gnibbler's answer, it's not actually the shortest solution, and any question tagged [code-golf] should pick the shortest solution as the winner.

Comment: Input is given how?

Comment: @Joey Standard Input

Comment: We should be able to write as a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Golfscript -- 22 chars

```
~2base.-1%="YES""NO"if
```

Answer (score 34):

### Python - 46 chars

```
n=bin(input())[2:]
print'YNEOS'[n!=n[::-1]::2]
```

Comment: Wow. What does `[n!=n[::-1]::2]` do?

Comment: @Dogbert, n[::-1] is a slice. The start and end indexs are empty, so it means the whole string. The stepsize is -1, so when you see [::-1] it is a short way to reverse a string/list etc. So n!=n[::-1] is True (ie 1) when n is not a palindrome. Therefore when n is a palindrome, you get 'YNEOS'[0::2] - start at 0 and take every 2nd character. When n is not a palindrome you get 'YNEOS'[1::2] - start at 1 and take every second character :)

Comment: I think people are voting for the slice trick :), rightly so. :P +1

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 85 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 10.625 bytes

*-6 bits thanks to @lyxal*

*-3 bits thanks to @the-thonnu*

```
bḂ≠`∨ȯno`½iN
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsImLhuILiiaBg4oioyK9ub2DCvWlOIiwiIiwiMVxuMlxuM1xuNFxuNVxuNlxuN1xuOFxuOVxuMTBcbjExXG4xMlxuMTNcbjE0XG4xNSJd)

```
b            # binary of input
 Ḃ≠          # is not equal to its reverse (essentially: is not a palindrome?)
   `∨ȯno`    # compressed string `yesno`
         ½   # split into two strings of equal length
          i  # index that inequality (0/1) into that
           N # case swapped to uppercase
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsIs6g4biCPeKAm25v4oCb4oioyK9cImnih6ciLCIiLCI1XG42Il0=) for 11.375 bytes

Comment: Or [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsIs6g4biCPeKAm25v4oCb4oioyK9cImnJviIsIiIsIjVcbjYiXQ==) for 11.125 bytes

Comment: [10.625 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsImLhuILiiaBg4oioyK9ub2DCvWlOIiwiIiwiMVxuMlxuM1xuNFxuNVxuNlxuN1xuOFxuOVxuMTBcbjExXG4xMlxuMTNcbjE0XG4xNSJd)

Answer (score 4):

**C <strike>84</strike> <strike>81</strike> 74 Characters**

```
r;main(v,x){for(scanf("%d",&v),x=v;v;v/=2)r=r*2|v&1;puts(r-x?"NO":"YES");}
```

It does not use any function like string reverse.

Comment: Couldn't you save a few characters changing `r<<=1` into `r*=2`, `v>>=1` into `v/=2` and `{}` into `;`?

Comment: @paxdiablo Indeed. Changed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `r*=2,r|=v&1` -> `r=r*2|v&1` (-2)

Comment: and moving that term to the body of the loop saves another byte.

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, <strike>41</strike> 39

```
$><<%w(YES NO)[(n="%b"%$*)<=>n.reverse]
```

Thanks to Michael Kohl's "%b"%gets trick.

Comment: Very nice, I like this a lot! +1 for using the spaceship in a creative way :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript - <strike>79</strike> 77 chars

```
alert((a=(prompt()*1).toString(2))-a.split("").reverse().join("")?"NO":"YES")
```

**More information**

`prompt()*1` :  Quick trick to convert string to number.

`.toString(2)` : That's how you convert to binary in javascript.

`a.split("").reverse().join("")` : There is no native support to reverse string, so you have to convert string to array and array to string.

`("[part1]" - "[part 2]")?"YES":"NO"` : `-` is a replacement for `!=` to save 1 char.

Comment: Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP - 41

```
<?=strrev($n=decbin(`cat`))==$n?@YES:@NO;
```

Test:

```
php 713.php <<< 5
YES
php 713.php <<< 6
NO
```

Comment: If you're going to use shell calls to get the input, might as well use `m4` instead of `cat` to save one.  There's also `pg` and `dd` (which writes some bytes to stderr).

Comment: Have You tried that on Windows? ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 45 characters

```
$_=sprintf'%b',shift;
print reverse==$_?YES:NO
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby, 43 characters**

```
puts((n="%b"%gets)==n.reverse ? "YES":"NO")
```

Comment: Save 2: `puts (n="%b"%gets)==n.reverse ? :YES: :NO`

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell, 67

```
('NO','YES')[($a=[Convert]::ToString("$input",2))-eq-join$a[64..0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, <s>17</s> 12 bytes

```
‘NO…Ü‘#EbÂQè
```

*-5 bytes thanks to Adnan.*

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYTk_igKbDnOKAmCNFYsOCUcOo&input=NQ)

Comment: Hey nice! I tried to golf it a bit and came to 12 bytes [`‘NO…Ü‘#EbÂQè`](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYTk_igKbDnOKAmCNFYsOCUcOo&input=NQ) :).

Comment: Great! I still don't know how to use/make compressed strings. Also, I didn't know the function `bin()` existed

Comment: There is actually a detailed example [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/67457#67457), if you are interested :).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <strike>75 bytes</strike> 69 bytes

```javascript
alert((a=[...(+prompt()).toString(2)]).some(x=>x-a.pop())?"NO":"YES")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDADAt5gpRezgKFQnVx2cHIMWqagJbZD@vroed9JLaYtBtHl496XQ5aMiksNaIt@iaIxVXjSG58DW2CRXUAT4OfHtMbs@V46ssPx1gGmGDtZxAVPKBw)

A different approach from [HoLyVieR's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/54/holyvier) solution

**Explanation**

`+prompt()` :  Converts string to number

`[...s]` : converts a string `s` to an array of chars

`.some((x) => x - a.pop())` : checks whether there is one element in the array that does not equal the last element of the array

**Edit**

69 chars, thanks to the suggestions by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcqxDkBADADQf7mpjehglByTlcEkYmi4CEGb04i/P978dn74nuOmll@yhJT4CNEA2I9EBJlGOdUAkUx6i9u1QoET0i1ngNdXb86kon@oXdu50g1N7zClDw), or [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9ZOI9E2Wk9PL0@vJD@4pCgzL13DSDNWU684PzdVo8LWrkI3Ua8gv0BDU9Neyc9fyUop0jVY6X8BUGGJRpqGqabmfwA) as a function.

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcGxCoAgEADQf3G6I7yhKYJoaq2hKSJQQkIplfPw9@29YKstN/ssug6t2dexwElEZYIuc/qyACJJ2oV9fKDHi9hVx8UBUkg@GqPLrNZNjepYdoWt/Q), or [53  bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9YuWk9Pr9g2T68kP7ikKDMvXcNIM1avKLUstag4VUNTLys/My8hQbfYXsnPX8lKKdI1WOl/AVBdiUaahqmm5n8A) as a function.

Comment: @Shaggy, thanks for the first one, I'll add it, as for the second one, I think it makes more sense to be suggested in HoLyVieR's answer

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 47 bytes

```arturo
print(=reverse<=as.binary do arg\0)?->'YES->'NO
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python (51)

```
n=bin(input())[2:]
print'YES'if n==n[::-1]else'NO'
```

Comment: You can `['NO','YES'][n==n[::-1]]`

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (73)

No string reverse:

```
print f(split//,sprintf'%b',shift);
sub f{@_<=1?YES:shift!=pop()?NO:f(@_)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (127)

This one constructs all palindromes up to 2^32.

```
sub f{
    my($x,$l)=@_;
    $l+=2,f(($x<<$_)+1+(1<<$l-1),$l)?return 1:0 for 1..15-$l/2;
    $x-$ARGV[0]?0:1
}
print f(0,1)+f(0,0)+f(1,1)?YES:NO
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash, 55 chars

```
C=`dc<<<$1\ 2op`;[ $C = `rev<<<$C` ]&&echo YES||echo NO
```

Comment: Well, technically that's `bash` *and* `dc` *and* `rev` :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell (79)

```
0?k=n;n?k=div n 2?(n`mod`2+k*2);f x|x==x?0="YES"|True="No";main=interact$f.read
```

Comment: Don't forget: In Haskell, this will work with really big numbers.

Comment: Ahm, that's actually 79 characters. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### J - 33 characters

```
13 : ';(]-:|.)#:y{''YES'';''NO'''
```

Answer (score 1):

### J: 24

```
((-:|.)#:x){2 3$'NO YES'
```

eg:

```
   ((-:|.)#:5){2 3$'NO YES'
YES
   ((-:|.)#:12){2 3$'NO YES'
NO
   ((-:|.)#:125){2 3$'NO YES'
NO
   ((-:|.)#:63){2 3$'NO YES'
YES
```

Answer (score 1):

### C (77 bytes)

```
r,t;main(n){for(t=n=atoi(gets(&n));n;r*=2,r|=n%2,n/=2);puts(r-t?"NO":"YES");}
```

[TEST](http://ideone.com/yFzEX)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 18 bytes

```
%2>"YNEOS"!qJ.BQ_J
```

Also 18 bytes:

```
@,"NO""YES"qJ.BQ_J
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, not competing

I wanted to do it without using strings at all.

iterative solution, 78 bytes

```
for($x=log($n=$argv[1],2);$i<$x&($n>>$i^$n>>$x-$i^1);$i++);echo$i<$x/2?NO:YES;
```

recursive solution, 113 bytes

```
function p($n,$x=0){return$n<2?$n:is_pal(($n&(1<<$x=log($n,2)/2)-1)^$n>>$x+!is_int($x));}echo p($argv[1])?YES:NO;
```

If `n` is a binary palindrome, the upper half xor the lower half is also a binary palindrome and vice versa.

---

a port of the excellent [C answer from fR0DDY](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/722#722), 58 bytes

```
for($x=2*$v=$argv[1];$x/=2;$r=$r*2|$x&1);echo$r-$v?NO:YES;
```

a binary reverse. Columbus´ egg.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>80</s> 78 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
.+
$*
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
^((.)*?).??((?<-2>.)*$)
$1¶$3
O$^`.(?=.*¶)

^(.*)¶\1
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCoKK2AoMSspXDEKJHsxfTAKMDEKMQpeKCguKSo_KS4_PygoPzwtMj4uKSokKQokMcK2JDMKTyReYC4oPz0uKsK2KQoKXiguKinCtlwx&input=NQ)

Convert to unary. Convert that to binary. Cut the number in half and remove a middle digit if there is one. Reverse the first half. Match if both halves are equal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes (non-competing)

```
BṚ⁼Bị“YES“NO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/0cOesR417nB7u7n7UMCfSNRhI@vn////fFAA)

Explanation:

```
BṚ⁼Bị“YES“NO Main link. Arguments: z.
B            Binary representation of z.
 Ṛ           Reversed.
   B         Binary representation of z.
  ⁼          Check if x is equal to y.
     “YES“NO [['Y', 'E', 'S'], ['N', 'O']]
    ị        xth element of y (1-indexed).
```

Before printing, Python's `str` function is mapped through a list, and then the elements are concatenated, so you see `YES` or `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
'NO' 'YES'⊃⍨≡∘⌽⍨2⊥⍣¯1⊢⎕
```

-3 bytes from Bubbler, after fitting the question requirements.

Instead of performing an if-else like below, this program uses APL's representation of true as 1 and false as 0 to select from an array, where 'NO' is in the 0th index and 'YES' is in the first index.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tO4HvXOrdZ41LP3UefCR12LNI0edS191Lv40HpDIO9R71Yr9UjXYPVH3S3qfv7qtUC9/0EMBYhoV/Oj3hUgjR0zQCb0rkDVDVQMtOI/ZxqXKReQMDQAAA)

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
{(⌽≡⊢)2(⊥⍣¯1)⍵:'YES'⋄'NO'}
```

### Explanation

```apl
{(⌽≡⊢)2(⊥⍣¯1)⍵:'YES'⋄'NO'}
{                        } function wrapper
             ⍵             take the right argument
      2(⊥⍣¯1)              convert to base 2, and split into -1 groups(gets all digits)
 (⌽≡⊢)                     reverse equals right expression?
              :'YES'⋄'NO'} if the above is true, display 'YES', otherwise 'NO'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//97KOKMveKJoeKKoikyKOKKpeKNo8KvMSnijbU6J1lFUyfii4QnTk8nff9m4oaQ4o2O4oqD4o2s4o20wq8z4oaR4o6VU1JD4o6VVEhJU/9mIDU)

Comment: @petStorm Right, somehow I didn't notice that either. Adding `⎕` at the end solves the problem.

Comment: You can write a full program with test cases on TIO [like this](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97X@1xqOevY86Fz7qWqRp9Khr6aPexYfWGwJ5j3q3WqlHugarP@puUffzV6991DcVpOU/ZxqXKReQMDQAAA). Some golfing gives [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tO4HvXOrdZ41LP3UefCR12LNI0edS191Lv40HpDIO9R71Yr9UjXYPVH3S3qfv7qtUC9/0EMBYhoV/Oj3hU4NQPVAm34z5nGZcoFJAwNAA) (which is the same length as [tacit](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55286392#55286392)).

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I'll fix it soon. Thanks for the help!

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tO4HvXOrdZ41LP3UefCR12LNI0edS191Lv40HpDIO9R71Yr9UjXYPVH3S3qfv7qtUC9/0EMBYhoV/Oj3hUgjR0zQCb0rkDVDVQMtOI/ZxqXKReQMDQAAA) with `(⌽≡⊢) → ≡∘⌽⍨` (because `≡∘⌽⍨x → x≡∘⌽x → x≡⌽x`)

Comment: A second commutation. Got it.

Comment: This really should have gotten a 100-rep bounty, not 200, so I'll skip one of your 100-rep bounties.

Comment: No worries. I figured as much.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes

```
If[PalindromeQ@IntegerDigits[#,2],"YES","NO"]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zMtOiAxJzMvpSg/NzXQwTOvJDU9tcglMz2zpDhaWccoVkcp0jVYSUfJz18pVu1/QFFmXomCQ3q0aez//wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [16 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
±î«Áýãf©¯tvf–É‰2
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=IllFUyJeKD1cfDo7Yil8fCJOTw==&input=NQo3CjE0)

## Explained

Unpacked: `"YES"^(=\|:;b)||"NO`. Man that yes/no required output really killed my byte count

```
    "YES"         String
  ^               Repeated
    (             Begin expression
        \         Fold with...
      =           ...equality
          |:      Bifurcate
              _   Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
            ;b    Binary representation
    )             End expression
||                Boolean OR
  "NO             String, ending quote implied
```

This works because empty strings are falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
?q_K.BQK"YES""NO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/374w3lvPKdBbKdI1WEnJz///f1MA)

```
?q_K.BQK"YES""NO
   K.BQ          // Assign binary input to K
?q_K   K         // Evaluate whether K and reversed K are equal
        "YES""NO // Ternary output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>11.5</s> 11 bytes (22 nibbles)

*Edit: -1 nibble thanks to xigoi*

```
?==;``@$\@"YES" "NO"
```

```
    ``@                 # get binary representation of
       $                # input
   ;                    # and save it;
 ==                     # is this equal to
        \               # reverse of 
         @              # itself?
?                       # if so:
           "YES"        #   output "YES"
                        # otherwise:
                 "NO"   #   output "NO"
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `==`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¢è¬?`y`u:"NO
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ouisP2B5g2B1OiJOTw&input=NQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃḲQ"YESNO"½i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWGx_uaH64Y1OgUqRrsJ-_0qG9mUuKk5KLobILFppCGAA)

Unfortunately, the Thunno 2 dictionary only holds words which are 4 letters or more, so neither `YES` nor `NO` can be compressed.

##### Explanation

```python
ḃḲQ"YESNO"½i  # Implicit input
ḃ             # Convert to binary
 ḲQ           # Not equal to its reverse?
              # (i.e. 0 if palindrome, 1 otherwise)
   "YESNO"    # String "YESNO"
          ½   # Halve to get ["YES", "NO"]
           i  # Index into the list
              # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haxe, 164 bytes

Works only with system platforms (php, neko, cpp, etc.). Takes input through command line arguments.

```
class T{static function main(){var r:Dynamic=Std.parseInt(Sys.args()[0]);var s=r.toString(2);trace(s==[for(i in-s.length+1...1)s.charAt(-i)].join('')?"YES":"NO");}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 71 bytes

```
function paly(n)
v=de2bi(n);
if v==v(numel(v):-1:1)
'YES'
else
'NO'
end
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
bÂQi'…Üë'€¸}u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vc2FiaWX//2LDglFpJ@KApsOcw6sn4oKswrh9df//NQ)

```
bÂQi'…Üë'€¸}u  # full program
   i           # if...
 Â             # implicit input...
b              # in binary...
  Q            # is equal to...
 Â             # implicit input...
b              # in binary...
 Â             # reversed...
    '…Ü        # then push "yes"
       ë       # else...
        '€¸    # push "no"
           }   # exit if statement
            u  # convert to uppercase
               # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 84 Bytes

```python
f=lambda x:['NO','YES'][int(bin(x)[2:]==(bin(x)[2:])[-1::-1])]
print(f(int(input())))
```

[Try online on TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocIqWt3PX11HPdI1WD02OjOvRCMpM0@jQjPayCrW1haJoxmta2hlpWsYqxnLVVAEUpimASIz8wpKSzQ0geD/fwA)

#### If just a pure function was allowed:

[Try pure function online (60 Bytes)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKlrdz19dRz3SNVg9Njozr0QjKTNPo0Iz2sgq1tYWiaMZrWtoZaVrGKsZ@z8tv0ihUiEzT6EoMS89VcPQwEDTiouzoAikPU2jUlPzPwA)

Comment: This seems valid. You don't need the `[-1::` in `[-1::-1]`. Just `[2:][::-1]` is enough

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2KTNPIzOvBIgLSks0NDU1o42sYrkKikBi0ep@/uo66pGuweqx0RW2thXRVla6hrGxmv//mwIA) by removing a lot of unnecessary stuff, or [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKlrdz19dRz3SNVg9NjopM0@jQjPayCrW1hbBjray0jWMjf1fUJSZV6KRpmGqqfkfAA) for a function

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 22 bytes

```
&p⊡≍⇌.⋯⋕&sc{"NO""YES"}
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__JnDiiqHiiY3ih4wu4ouv4ouVJnNjeyJOTyIiWUVTIn0K)