# Depalindromize this string!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, palindrome

Given a palindrome generated according to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98325/palindromize-this-string), depalindromize it.

#### Test cases

```
abcdedcba -> abcde
johncenanecnhoj -> johncena
ppapapp -> ppap
codegolflogedoc -> codegolf
```

As this is about depalindromizing, **your code cannot be a palindrome**.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: -1 for the pointless restriction on your code not being a palindrome. It adds nothing to the challenge IMO, in very few languages would it matter.

Comment: +1 for the restriction. It´s so mirroring the paliondrome challenge ... and it´s adding challenge to esolangs. I like it. Am I correct in the assumption that input will always have an uneven length?

Comment: The non-palindrome restriction is probably a joke based on the previous challenge. Did anyone really downvote based on that?

Comment: @Titus for that challenge, it almost always required extra work to make the code a palindrome. Here, it almost always requires no extra work to make the code _not_ a palindrome.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Don't you see the symmetry? It's quite beautiful, if I do say so myself. But to be serious, I really don't see anything wrong with the so-called "pointless restriction" that would warrant a downvote. It might be trivial, but it's not the main focus of the challenge. The main focus of the challenge is to depalindromize the string, not to create a non-palindromic code.

Comment: @MamaFunRoll I feel that it adds nothing to the challenge, and might as well not be there, and thus probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk You could also argue that because it adds nothing to the challenge, it might as well be there as nothing will happen either way. Really, in this case the final say goes to the OP. After all, it's sort of nice to have complementary challenges like this.

Comment: It does prevent single-byte solutions. @diynevala +1 for the unnecessary +1.

Comment: @Adám So it is essentially "do X without Y" challenge as well. My +1 is not unnecessary, as it supports the choice to restrict palindromous code

Comment: @LuisMendo No, it's not a joke, the [tag:restricted-source] tag exists. I have -1'd.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer But the restriction is virtually ineffective. It's very unlikely that the unrestricted code turns out to be palindromic

Comment: @LuisMendo Hypothesis: What if I made a language which happened to have an depalindromize operator (let's say `q`)? I couldn't use it if I didn't do `<space>q` instead :(

Comment: Palindrome tag is not appropriate here, is there a "non-palindrome" tag? :)

Comment: What if the string is not a palindrome to begin with?

Comment: What is expected output when the string is one char long? What is the expected output for empty string (is empty string a palindrome to begin with?)?

Comment: @LuisMendo BTW, I didn't -1 but I also didn't +1.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk You must not play Magic the Gathering.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile I agree with the notion of that. I almost only see special forms of list accessing, instead of interesting logic, simply because recognizing palindromes does not seem to be a requirement.

Answer (score 14):

## Julia, <s>21</s> 15 bytes

```
x->x[1:end/2+1]
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=cHJpbnQoKHgtPnhbMTplbmQvMisxXSkoImFiY2RlZGNiYSIpKQ&input=) (extra code is for printing output)

Comment: `end/2` is cool feature

Comment: @Downgoat yes, dennis showed it to me.

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
2ä¬
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MsOkwqw&input=YWJjZGVkY2Jh)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 23 bytes

I am not able to test on my phone, but this should work:

```
lambda s:s[:-~len(s)/2]
```

Comment: If you are running on android, you can use QPython from the google play store. It's the best I've found :)

Comment: [termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en) `apt-get install python2`

Comment: @Matt That's overkill if all you want is Python.

Comment: @Matt as well as that if you can find `apt-get` on your phone, it's probably not a normal phone.

Comment: @MathManiac termux is installed from Google Play onto any non rooted Android phone. Can't get much more normal than that.

Answer (score 6):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 4 bytes

```
2.^/
```

I spent a while searching for a language in which this challenge is short, and realized I was dumb and my own language did that.

Answer (score 5):

## 05AB1E, 5 bytes

```
Dg;î£
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RGc7w67Cow&input=am9obmNlbmFuZWNuaG9q)

**Explanation:**

```
D      Duplicate
 g;î   Divide length by two and round up
    £  First b letters of a
```

Answer (score 5):

## Cheddar, <s>22</s> 18 bytes

```
@.head($0.len/2+1)
```

So simple I don't think needs explanation but I'll add one if wanted.

[Try it online](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=bGV0IGY9IEAuaGVhZCgkMC5sZW4vMisxKTsKCnByaW50IGYoImpvaG5jZW5hbmVjbmhvaiIpOw&input=)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - 4 bytes

```
hc2Q
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hc2Q&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abcdedcba%22%0A%22johncenanecnhoj%22%0A%22ppapapp%22%0A%22codegolflogedoc%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>32 26</s> 25 bytes

1 byte saved thanks to Neil:

```js
s=>s.slice(0,-s.length/2)
```

```js
f=
  s=>s.slice(0,-s.length/2)
;
console.log(f('abcdedcba'))
console.log(f('johncenanecnhoj'))
console.log(f('ppapapp'))
console.log(f('codegolflogedoc'))
```

---

**Previous solutions**
26 bytes thanks to Downgoat:

```js
s=>s.slice(0,s.length/2+1)
```

32 bytes:

```js
s=>s.slice(0,(l=s.length/2)+l%2)
```

Comment: You can shorten to just `s=>s.slice(0,s.length/2+1)` Since length will always be odd

Comment: @Downgoat thanks to you I found that for one more byte `s=>s.slice(0,s.length/2+.5)` would work for even length too.

Comment: `-s.length/2` works for both odd and even lengths.

Answer (score 4):

## WinDbg, <s>87</s> 71 bytes

```
db$t0 L1;.for(r$t1=@$t0;@$p;r$t1=@$t1+1){db$t1 L1};da$t0 L(@$t1-@$t0)/2
```

*-16 bytes by not inserting NULL, instead passing length to `da`*

Input is passed in via an address in psuedo-register `$t0`. For example:

```
eza 2000000 "abcdedcba"       * Write string "abcdedcba" into memory at 0x02000000
r $t0 = 33554432              * Set $t0 = 0x02000000
* Edit: Something got messed up in my WinDB session, of course r $t0 = 2000000 should work
* not that crazy 33554432.
```

It works by replacing the right of middle char (or right-middle if the string has even length) with a null and then prints the string from the original starting memory address.

```
db $t0 L1;                                   * Set $p = memory-at($t0)
.for (r $t1 = @$t0; @$p; r $t1 = @$t1 + 1)   * Set $t1 = $t0 and increment until $p == 0
{
    db $t1 L1                                * Set $p = memory-at($t1)
};
da $t0 L(@$t1-@$t0)/2                        * Print half the string
```

Output:

```
0:000> eza 2000000 "abcdeedcba"
0:000> r $t0 = 33554432
0:000> db$t0 L1;.for(r$t1=@$t0;@$p;r$t1=@$t1+1){db$t1 L1};da$t0 L(@$t1-@$t0)/2
02000000  61                                               a
02000000  61                                               a
02000001  62                                               b
02000002  63                                               c
02000003  64                                               d
02000004  65                                               e
02000005  65                                               e
02000006  64                                               d
02000007  63                                               c
02000008  62                                               b
02000009  61                                               a
0200000a  00                                               .
02000000  "abcde"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 27 bytes

```
take=<<succ.(`div`2).length
```

Pointfree version of

```
\x->take(div(length x)2+1)x
```

which is also 27 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
9LQ2/)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OUxRMi8p&input=J2NvZGVnb2xmbG9nZWRvYyc)

#### Explanation

```
9L       % Push array [1, 1j]
  Q      % Add 1: transforms into [2, 1+1j]
   2/    % Divide by 2: transforms into [1, 0.5+0.5j]
     )   % Apply as index into implicit input. The array [1, 0.5+0.5j] used as an index
         % is interpreted as [1:0.5+end*0.5]
```

Comment: Wow, that is a very neat way to handle complex values as arguments for slicing

Comment: @miles Thanks! Yes, it's handy. The imaginary unit works as `end`, and colons between the array elements are implicit

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
œs2Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZNzMuG4og&input=&args=J2FiY2RlZGJjYSc)

#### Explanation

```
œs2      Split input into 2 chunks of similar lengths. For odd-length input,
         the first chunk is the longest
   Ḣ     Keep the first chunk
```

Answer (score 3):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 12 bytes

Two *completely* different solutions, both 12 bytes.

```
ò"Bx$xh|ò"bP
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w7IiQngkeGh8w7IiYlA&input=YWJjZGVkY2Jh)

```
Ó./&ò
MjdGÍî
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w5MuLybDsgpNamRHw43Drg&input=YWJjZGVkY2Jh)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
@2tr
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=QDJ0cg&input=InBwYXBhcHAi&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
@2        Split in half
  t       Take the second half
   r      Reverse it
```

If the input has odd length, the second half generated by `@2` is the one that is the longest, that is the one we should return (after reversing it).

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, 57 bytes

```java
String c(String s){return s.substring(0,s.length()/2+1);}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` (so it's 57 bytes).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
⊢↑⍨2÷⍨1+≢
```

`⊢` the argument

`↑⍨` truncated at

`2÷⍨` half of

`1+` one plus

`≢`  the length

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u22A2%u2191%u23682%F7%u23681+%u2262%20%u22C4%20f%A8%27abcdedcba%27%20%27johncenanecnhoj%27%20%27ppapapp%27%20%27codegolflogedoc%27&run)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 15 bytes

Includes +2 for `-lp`

Give input string on STDIN:

```
depal.pl <<< "HelleH"
```

`depal.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lp
s/../chop/reg
```

The `-l` is not really needed if you input the palindrome without final newline, but I included it to be fair to the other perl solutions that use it.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 40 bytes

```
<?=substr($a=$argv[1],0,1+strlen($a)/2);
```

`strlen($a)/2` gets cast to int, with the input always having odd length, `+1` suffices to round up.

**42 bytes** for any length:

```
<?=substr($a=$argv[1],0,(1+strlen($a))/2);
```

for unknown length, `(1+strlen)/2` gets cast to int, rounding up `strlen/2`.

Comment: As the input is defined as coming from this (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98325/palindromize-this-string) challenge it's length will always be odd, so you can just go with your shorter one.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 14 bytes

Standard function. Returns string from index 1 to index (length/2 + 1/2).

```
sub(Ans,1,.5+.5length(Ans
```

Answer (score 2):

## GameMaker Language, 59 bytes

```
a=argument0 return string_copy(a,1,ceil(string_length(a)/2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>31</s> 30 bytes

Saving 1 byte thanks to Cyoce.

```c
f(char*c){c[-~strlen(c)/2]=0;}
```

Usage:

```c
main(){
 char a[]="hellolleh";
 f(a);
 printf("%s\n",a);
}
```

Comment: @KevinCruijssen fixed

Comment: Hi, sorry I deleted my comment. I was correct in saying it won't work for even palindromes. But, since this is the reverse of that other challenge, there won't be any test cases for even palindromes.. Sorry about that, you can undo your change. +1 from me. :)

Comment: Well, it has the same length now, works for even+odd and looks golfier. I am okay with this.

Comment: This is arguably a memory leak :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR In case it was a `malloc`'ed string, the memory manager does not know if it is a string or anything else, so the `free` would free everything

Comment: Good point! (We're keeping around memory during the program's execution that we don't need, but you're right that when the string is freed, all of its memory is freed.)

Comment: I think you can remove the space in `char* c`

Comment: @Cyoce Yes i can, thank you!

Comment: Does setting the middle character to zero delete the rest of the string? (Not too familiar with C)

Comment: @Cyoce A string in C is delimited by a `\0`, so printing it afterwards yields only the first half. Technically, the tail is still present, but all string related functions only count up to the `\0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 5 bytes

```
l½KßH
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=bMK9S8OfSA&input=ImpvaG5jZW5hbmVjbmhvaiI)

*-1 byte thanks to Sherlock9*

Explanation:

```
l½K@H
l½K    ceil(len(input)/2)
   ßH  first (len(input)//2 + 1) characters of input
```

Comment: 6 bytes: `;l½K@H` :D

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 23 + 2 (`-pl` flag) = <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
perl -ple '$_=substr$_,0,1+y///c/2'
```

Ungolfed:

```perl
while (<>) {             # -p flag
    chomp($_)            # -l flag
    $_ = substr($_, 0, 1 + length($_) / 2);
    print($_, "\n")      # -pl flag
}
```

Thanx to @ardnew.

Comment: you can save 3 chars by replacing `length()` with `y|||c`

Answer (score 2):

## Dip, 8 bytes

```
H{C'0ÏEI
```

Explanation:

```
           # Implicit input
 H         # Push length of input
  {        # Add 1
   C       # Divide by 2
    '      # Convert to int
     0Ï    # Get string back
       E   # Push prefixes of string
        I  # Push prefixes[a]
           # Implicit print
```

This could probably be much improved.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
<zh/lz2
```

Saved 1 with thanks to @Steven H

Not the shortest Pyth answer (by half) but I'm making an effort to learn the language and this is my first post using it. Posted as much for comments and feedback as anything. It's also the first Pyth program that I have actually got to work :)

Now I just need to work out how the 4 byte answer from @Maltysen works :-)

Comment: If you still want to know how Maltysen's answer works, it `c`hops the input `Q` into `2` pieces and takes the first piece using `h` (which, thanks to the implementation of chop, will grab the center letter as well).  As for your code, you could replace `+1` with `h`, the built-in for incrementing numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the `h` hint @Steven H. There are so many built-ins I guess it just takes some time to find them all :)

Comment: No problem! If you ever need any help, try pinging me in the Nineteenth byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 14 + 3 (`-lF` flag) = <s>19</s> 17 bytes

For 5.20.0+:

```
perl -lF -E 'say@F[0..@F/2]'
```

For 5.10.0+ (19 bytes):

```
perl -nlaF -E 'say@F[0..@F/2]'
```

Ungolfed:

```perl
while (<>) {             # -n flag (implicitly sets by -F in 5.20.0+)
    chomp($_)            # -l flag
    @F = split('', $_);  # -aF flag (implicitly sets by -F in 5.20.0+)
    say(@F[0 .. (scalar(@F) / 2)]);
}
```

Thanx to @simbabque.

Comment: You can save two bytes, you don't need to set `-n` and `-a` because `-F` does so implicitly.

Comment: @simbabque Yes. But for 5.20.0+ only.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge](http://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
~:0`!#v_\1+
0:-2,\_@#`
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=fjowYCEjdl9cMSsKMDotMixcX0AjYA&input=Y29kZWdvbGZsb2dlZG9j)

---

Befunge has no string or array type so the everything is done on the stack one character at a time. The first loop (on the top line) counts the number of characters read (swapping with less than 2 elements in the stack produces an initial 0). The second (on the middle line) prints characters while counting down twice as fast. As a result only the last half of the input is printed, but LIFO so it's in the correct order.

Thanks to [Brian Gradin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61606/brian-gradin) for a better version of the first loop.

Comment: You beat me by half an hour and 7 bytes :)
http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=K346MGAhI3ZfXDEKLzIrJTI6JDx2Cl9AIzotMSxcPA&input=Y29kZWdvbGZsb2dlZG9j

Comment: @BrianGradin, nice. now I've beat beat you by 9 bytes ;)

Comment: Ah, ok. I see what you did. Didn't occur to me to count down by two rather than calculate the actual number of characters to print. Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

### Brainfuck, 20 bytes

```
,
[
  [>,]
  <[<]
  >.,>[>]
  <<
]
```

[Try it online.](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFtbPixdPFs8XT4uLD5bPl08PF0&input=YWJjZGVkY2JhCg)

This saves a byte over the more straightforward approach of consuming the input before starting the main loop:

```
,[>,]
<
[
  [<]
  >.,>[>]
  <,<
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 23 bytes

```
lambda x:x[:len(x)/2+1]
```

Comment: I think this requires Python 2; you should indicate that in your answer

Comment: @LuisMendo oh, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB / Octave, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 16 bytes

*1 byte off borrowing an idea from [Easterly Irk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98349/36398) (add `1` instead of `.5`)*
*2 bytes off thanks to @StewieGriffin (unnecessary parentheses)*

```
@(x)x(1:end/2+1)
```

[Try it at Ideone](http://ideone.com/c4otjN).

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks! I don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: Neither do I :P It's not like it's a "trick" you didn't know about... I've had a few of those too :)

Answer (score 1):

## C# <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```cs
s=>string.Join("",s.Where((_,i)=>i<=s.Count()/2));
```

It's a lambda, woo!
You can catch it with:

```cs
Func<string,string> f=<your lambda here>
```

it requires the string to be a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 4 bytes

```
le>_
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=le%3E_&input=hellolleh)

```
l    -    len(input)
 e   -   ^//2
  >  -  input[^:]
   _ - reversed(^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 21 bytes

```
@Left(a;@Length(a)/2)
```

Computed field that takes input from an editable field a. Works because Notes rounds up when an odd number is divided by 2.

Test Cases

[image: test case 1]

[image: test case 2]

[image: test case 3]

[image: test case 4]

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 24 bytes

I basically took this from [another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95583/34718) of mine.

```
^((.)*?.??)(?<-2>.)*$
$1
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XigoLikqPy4_PykoPzwtMj4uKSokCiQx&input=Y29kZWdvbGZsb2dlZG9j)

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 48 bytes

```
(substring s 0(+ 1(floor(/(string-length s)2))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s)
  (substring s 0 (+ 1
                    (floor
                     (/ (string-length s)
                        2)))))
```

Testing:

```
(f "abcdedcba")
(f "johncenanecnhoj")
(f "ppapapp")
(f "codegolflogedoc")
```

Output:

```
"abcde"
"johncena"
"ppap"
"codegolf"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 7 bytes

```
r_,-2/<
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cl8sLTIvPA&input=Y29kZWdvbGZsb2dlZG9j)

Answer (score 1):

## [GO](https://golang.org/), 43 bytes

`func(s string)string{return s[:len(s)/2+1]}`

[Try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/XlvEKlUMDQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 22 bytes

```
lambda _:_[len(_)/2:]
```

Depalindromizes a given string. Still fails on all the test cases. Weird... ;-)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! However, I get `edcba` instead of `abcde` when I give the string `abcdedcba`. Please fix this.

Comment: You can actually fix it by changing `len(_)/2:` to `:-~len(_)/2`.

Comment: @Oliver It is depalindromized ;p I'll fix it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5, 87 Bytes

```
x=list(input())
for q in range(0,int(round((len(x)/2)-0.1,0))):x.pop()
print(''.join(x))
```

i'm new to this codegolfing, but it's to be fun. I probably won't win but oh well.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 56 bytes

This is awful, but I just wanted to do it in Hexagony :)

Golfed:

```
,<_..){/"./..\&..$@....>;{.....'..>"+"+"&"='&'&=}\}=.:(<
```

In a hexagon:

```
     , < _ . .
    ) { / " . /
   . . \ & . . $
  @ . . . . > ; {
 . . . . . ' . . >
  " + " + " & " =
   ' & ' & = } \
    } = . : ( <
     . . . . .
```

Way to many no-ops...

Answer (score 1):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>7</s> 15 bytes

```
l1+2,[v
 ;!?lo<
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=DYRg1ATANA2gbgKAAQG4CEB+YB7APEA)

This is a full program. To use it simply place the palindrome on the stack, and the result will be outputted to stdout!

**Explanation**

```
l       get the stack length
 1+     add one
   2,   divide by two
     [  pop the value, create a new stack of that length
```

That's the meat of it, `ol?!;` just outputs until the stack is empty.

### [*><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish), 11 bytes (non-competing)

```
l5+2,]r{[$.
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=IYRgwgfA8g9gNgfgK4EIA+BuAUHArAagCYAaAXQCcBvAbQBIA6IA) (first line is a program that calls the function, outputs the stack, then exits)

This is a function. To use it simply call it (instruction `C`) with the palindrome on the stack, and the result will be on the stack! This part is non-competing because *><> is younger than the challenge.

**Explanation**

```
l             get the stack length
 5+           add five
   2,         divide by two
     ]        close the stack
      r       reverse the stack
       {      shift the stack left
        [     pop the value on the end, create a new stack of that length
         $    swap the two values on the end of the stack
          .   jump back, with the result on the stack
```

For ><> coders who might be confused by this, a new stack is created when a function is called, so you can actually call `]` right from the start if you're inside a function. The data inside this stack is the `x, y` coordinate of the ><> when `C` was called.

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 7 bytes

```
^(!2/|_
```

That is easy but really hard to golf.

### Explanation

```
^       # Input in the right order
 (!2/   # Repeat half of length times:
     |_ # Pop the stack
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/TkPRSL8m/v//5PyU1PT8nLSc/PTUlPxkAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
substr(x<-scan(,''),1,nchar(x)/2+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCoAgEAXvfYYXlYyocz/zXAQRWyMN@vttu8zAHOYW6U/s43bvsXQCu2CtD1tgytDo133evJjSMlNicCLOrZjJIFKEeoAaYfzlBOOqCv2gXooTRj4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
½h
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiwr1oIiwiIiwiaGVsbG9sbGVoIl0=)

Makes a list of each half of the string and takes the first item. Vyxal rounds up when splitting odd numbers in half. Don't think this can be golfed to 1 byte because the code can't be a palindrome :p

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
->s{s[0..s.size/2]}
```

Comment: you can use `size`

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 27 bytes

```
f[x]=[x]
f(a:b)=a:f(init b)
```

No indexing. Recursively takes from the start and end, keeping letters from the end.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
*.substr(0,1+* div 2)
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
*\            # Whatever lambda
.substr(
  0,
  1 + * div 2 # Whatever lambda
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 9 bytes

```
⊢↑⍨2÷⍨1+⍴
```

Thanks to  Adám for saving 4 bytes.

Comment: I just saw your answer now. You should know that constants are allowed as the left tine of a fork, so `2÷⍨` works. Since constants are only allowed as left tine, you can swap the arguments of commutative functions to make them permitted, so `1+⍴` works. For non-commutative functions, use `⍨`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 45 bytes

```
([][()]<>){({}[()()])<>{}<>}<>{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdWygpXTw-KXsoe31bKCkoKV0pPD57fTw-fTw-eyh7fTw-KTw-fTw-&input=YWJjZGVkY2Jh&args=LWM)

42 bytes of code, and `+3` for the -c flag which enables ASCII input and output.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3,  <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

Python 3 strings don't like non-int indexes...

```
lambda S:S[:len(S)//2+1]
```

Alternatively, with the same byte count,

```
lambda S:S[:-~len(S)//2]
```

Comment: I think you can use one `/` for the second one

Comment: @Farhan.K no - in py3, `/` creates a float which is not a valid index, so floordiv (`//`) has to be used. The single slash, however, works in python 2

Comment: Oh right, didn't see that it was python 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 57 bytes

```
String c(String s){return s.substring(0,-~s.length()/2);}
```

At first I misinterpreted the question and also made code that supported even palindromes (which isn't necessary due to this being the reverse of that other challenge, and therefore there aren't any even palindrome test-cases). So I deleted my answer.
After seeing [*@KarlNapf*'s great answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98407/52210) however, I undeleted and edited this. It's the same byte count as the [other Java 7 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98415/52210), but works for both odd and even length palindromes (although only odd were asked for this challenge).

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/QEDacx)

```
class M{
  static String c(String s){
    return s.substring(0, -~s.length()/2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("abcdedcba"));
    System.out.println(c("abcddcba"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abcde
abcd
```

Comment: [i post it before you and this time i beat you](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98415/58766)

Comment: @Numberknot It fails on palindromes of even length though. :) `"abcddcba"` outputs `abcdd` instead of `abcd`.

Comment: @Numberknot Nevermind, I'm an idiot. Although I'm correct in saying it doesn't work for even palindromes, since this is the reverse of that other challenge, there won't be any test cases for even palindromes. I'll delete my answer..

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 26 bytes

```
lambda c:c[:(len(c)+1)//2]
```

This squeezes 2 chars out of the other Python3 answer by replacing the `int()` with division with `//`.

Comment: You could replace `len(c)+1` with `-~len(c)` and remove the parentheses

Comment: or `len(c)//2+1` as I did in my solution

Answer (score 0):

## R, 59 bytes

Not pretty but it gets the job done.

```
cat(strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]][0:(nchar(x)%/%2)+1],sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

### [GolfSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/GolfSharp), 20 bytes

```
v=>v.R(0,v.L()/2+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, <del>46</del> 36 bytes

Unfortunately there's no PowerShell on Try it Online. Alas, here's my attempt.

`$args[0][0..(($args[0].Length-1)/2)]`

Comment: This seems to print the characters on different lines. https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@SWJReHG0QG22gp6ehAePp@aTmpZdk6Bpq6htpxv7//z85PyU1PT8nLSc/PTUlPxkA Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yeah, it does. As far as the rules go this should be fine though.

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time/86385#86385), 18 bytes

```
;?left$$|(A,_lA|/2)
```

`;` gets a command line parameter, then we print the left half of it using `_l`. Works fine for even and odd-length strings.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 28 bytes

```
x=...print(x:sub(1,#x//2+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp, 43

```
(lambda(s)(subseq s 0(ceiling(length s)2)))
```

Truly hard to golf without accidentally writing a palindrome, will all those `(` matching opposite `)`.

<sub>I know, this is not what "palindrome" means.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [Element](http://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 11 bytes

```
_2:$'[(`)#]
```

[Try it online!](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=XzI6JCdbKGApI10&input=Y29kZWdvbGZsb2dlZG9j)

```
_2:$'[(`)#]
_             take input
 2:           make a second copy
   $          length of string
    '[    ]   FOR loop
     [(`  ]   chop off then print the first character
     [  )#]   chop off then discard the last character
```

The FOR loop is actually executed about twice as many times as it needs to be, but those extra iterations do not affect the output since it runs out of data to print.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 21 bytes

```
a=>a.take(a.size/2+1)
```

requires an assignment with a type annotation: `val f:(Seq[_]=>Seq[_])...`

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 30 bytes

Clojure port of basically every answer here:

```clj
#(subs % 0(inc(/(count %)2)))
```

Should be self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 33 bytes

Same logic as @Numberknot, but with 24 less bytes due to the use of lambdas. I tried to add this as an update to @Numberknot but with no response therefore I posted this as a separate answer since it's a big difference in bytes between his and my answer.

```
s->s.substring(0,s.length()/2+1);
```

Ungolfed version:

```
interface Func { String foo(String s); }


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Func s = s->s.substring(0,s.length()/2+1);           
    }
}
```

Comment: why -1? The other Java answers are pretty much the same only written in Java 7. Java 8 with the use of lambdas makes the answer shorter.

Comment: Probably because it looks like you just copied @Numberknot's [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98415/55508), without giving him any credit...

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 26 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Remove(s.Length/2+1);
```

This removes the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 35 bytes

Always late to the party.

```
substr(x<-scan(,""),1,nchar(x)/2+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

```
->n{n[0,-~n.size/2]}
```

anonymous lambda that returns the first half (rounded up) of a string. The `-~n` is a `1+n` with a higher priority than the division by two, so I don't need any parentheses. Unlike the other Ruby solution, this works on strings with even lengths.

**Usage**:

```
->n{n[0,-~n.size/2]}["abba"]
->n{n[0,-~n.size/2]}["abcba"]
->n{n[0,-~n.size/2]}["a"]
```

**Returns**:

```
"ab"
"abc"
"a"
```

Answer (score 0):

## OIL, 61 bytes

```
5
0
12
0
26
1
26
24
14
div
0
24
1
0
19
8
19
13
27

0
4
0
3

2
```

This uses the `div` from the [standard library](https://github.com/L3viathan/oil-stdlib).

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¯ÒUÊz
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=r9JVyno&input=ImNvZGVnb2xmbG9nZWRvYyI)