# Twisting Sentences

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

### Rules

The program should receive a string/array of words as input. For each word in the string/array, it will reconstruct the word by taking characters in alternating fashion from the front and back of the word.

12345 678 9 -> 15243 687 9.

It will then rearrange the words in an alternating fashion between the earliest and the latest occurring word in the string.

15243 687 9 -> 15243 9 687

Finally, it will reconstruct the string by placing the spaces, tabs and newlines at the indexes where they were initially located before outputting the result.

12345 678 9-> 15243 687 9 -> 15243 9 687 -> 15243 968 7

Output should be the same datatype as the input.

[Standard Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden

### Examples

> Input:
> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
> Output:
> Teh d.ogq kucil yaz bnrwo tehf xoo rvej supm
>
> Input:
> The quick brown fox jumps
> over the lazy dog.
> Output:
> Teh d.ogq kucil yaz bnrwo
> tehf xoo rvej supm
>
> Input:
> Aflack
> Output:
> Akfcla

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins

Comment: This feels like a duplicate. I swear I've seen this before.

Comment: So only tab, space and newline characters are not considered part of a word?

Comment: @JonathanAllan that is correct

Comment: Can we assume ASCII? or Unicode?

Comment: @MayorMonty You can assume the characters are whichever form makes it easier for you so long as it treats spaces properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15 14</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

A **whopping** 6 byte save from **Dennis** (by moving the flatten and mould inside link 1 there is no need to split into two and head, and a flatten is there already so they become one!)

```
żṚFṁ
Ç€Ç
```

(from the two lines: `żṚFœs2Ḣ`, and `Ç€ÇFṁ⁸`)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390z8Ods9we7mzkOtz@qGnN4fb/h9u9//@PVgrJSFXSUSoszUzOBtJJRfnleUA6Lb8CSGaV5hYUA@n8stQiIFUCVpqTWFUJpFLy0/WUYgE)**

Takes an array of words and returns an array of new words. (The Footer at TIO calls this and joins the array with spaces so it prints out nicely.)

*Note - handling a single string, splitting on tabs spaces and newlines, then reassembling was actually proving rather tricky; once I saw that a list of words was an option things got a lot easier!*

#### How?

```
Ç€Ç - Main link: list of words
Ç€  - call the last link (1) as a monad for €ach word
  Ç - call the last link (1) as a monad for the result

żṚFṁ - Link 1: Do a twist: list (here, a list of words or characters)
                            e.g. input = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G]
ż    - zip the list with                 [A,    B,    C,    D,    E,    F,    G]
 Ṛ   - the reverse of the list             [G,    F,    E,    D,    C,    B,    A]
                                        [[A,G],[B,F],[C,E],[D,D],[E,C],[F,B],[G,A]]
  F  - flatten into a single list        [A,G,  B,F,  C,E,  D,D,  E,C,  F,B,  G,A]
                                         [A,G,B,F,C,E,D,D,E,C,F,B,G,A]
   ṁ - mould like the input list         [A,G,B,F,C,E,D]
```

Comment: This should work. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390z8Ods9we7mzkOtz@qGnN4fb/h9u9//@PVgrJSFXSUSoszUzOBtJJRfnleUA6Lb8CSGaV5hYUA@n8stQiIFUCVpqTWFUJpFLy0/WUYgE "Jelly – TIO Nexus")

Comment: Sweet save; too easy to forget that manoeuvre!

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 89 bytes

Takes and outputs an array of words.

```js
a=>a.map(w=>(F=([a,...b])=>a?a+(b.pop()||'')+F(b):'')(a.map(F)).slice(p,p+=w.length),p=0)
```

**Test**

```js
let f =

a=>a.map(w=>(F=([a,...b])=>a?a+(b.pop()||'')+F(b):'')(a.map(F)).slice(p,p+=w.length),p=0)

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    f(["The","quick","brown","fox","jumps","over","the","lazy","dog."])
  )
);
```

#### String version, 112 bytes

Takes and outputs a string.

```js
s=>s.replace(/\S+/g,w=>(F=([a,...b])=>a?a+(b.pop()||'')+F(b):'')(s.split(/\s/).map(F)).slice(p,p+=w.length),p=0)
```

**Test**

```js
let f =

s=>s.replace(/\S+/g,w=>(F=([a,...b])=>a?a+(b.pop()||'')+F(b):'')(s.split(/\s/).map(F)).slice(p,p+=w.length),p=0)

console.log(f(`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`))

console.log(f(`The quick brown fox jumps
over the lazy dog.`))

console.log(f(`Aflack`))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 77 bytes

74 bytes of code + 3 bytes for `-0pa` flags.

```perl
map{s/.\K/chop/ge,s/../chop/reg}@F;s/\S/($r||=$F[$i++].pop@F)=~s%.%%,$&/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#U1YsSC3KUdA1KEj8n5tYUF2srxfjrZ@ckV@gn56qA@TpQThFqem1Dm7WxfoxwfoaKkU1NbYqbtEqmdrasXoF@QUObpq2dcWqeqqqOipqQI3//4dkpCoUlmYmZyskFeWX5ymk5VcoZJXmFhRz5ZelFimUAKVzEqsqFVLy0/UA)

Saved 8 bytes thanks to an old [@Ton Hospel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51507/ton-hospel)'s [post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98709/55508) where I "stole" `s/../chop/reg`. (I previously had `$c=y///c/2,s/.{$c}$//`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 84 bytes

```perl6
{my &t={(|(.shift,.pop)xx*)[^$_]}
map({|t [.comb]},t [$_]).rotor($_».chars)».join}
```

Inputs and outputs a list of words.

#### How it works

Inside the lambda, I defined another lambda to perform the "*taking characters in alternating fashion from the front and back*" twisting:

```perl6
my &t={                        }   # Lambda, assigned to a variable.
          .shift,.pop              # Remove an element from the front an back,
                      xx*          # an infinite number of times,
        |(           )             # and make sure this infinite list is flattened.
                          [^$_]    # Take as many elements as the input had elements.
```

This works because the `xx` operator is more like a macro than a function, in that it provides magic lazy evaluation.

Then in the main lambda:

```perl6
                   [$_]                          # Create a fresh array from the input,
                 t                               # and twist it (destructively).
map({          },                                # For each element (i.e. word):
      t [.comb]                                  #   Split it into characters and twist them,
     |                                           #   and slip them into the outer list.
                        .rotor($_».chars)        # Partition this flat list of characters,
                               $_».chars         # using the original word lengths.
                                         ».join  # Turn each sub-list into a word.
```

---

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 87 bytes

```perl6
{my &t={(|(.shift,.pop)xx*)[^$_]}
my @a=map {|t [.comb]},t [.words];S:g/\S/{@a.shift}/}
```

This is a variation of the above, which inputs and outputs a string – preserving different whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>115 95 93 98</s> 95 bytes

```hs
f(a:b)=a:f(reverse b)
f e=e
a!(y:z)|elem y" \t\n"=y:a!z|b:c<-a=b:c!z
a!z=z
(!)=<<(f=<<).f.words
```

Call with `(!)=<<(f=<<).f.words $ "some string"`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bY6xDoMgFEV3vuJhOsBi0nQjkvQjOro89NHaKljEWoj/bvmALme55ybnsAKVkRqVFYE@FBYCI5kF0sTwKozqJBdJZbnTSBOkCtrYukonhTzv5@aii8IzI27LQ3Cpm0bYAlnbevOhX44JBwcaBhcpYBfhBH@124PgvQ7dC0zwmwPrv/Bcp3lhvnRBLPOIOUHv7/UP)

Thanks to @nimi for pointing out that I misread the challenge earlier.

The function `f` performs the twisting on a list, so it can be used on strings (list of chars) and a list of strings. 
`a!b` inserts the whitespace of string `b` into string `a`.

`(!)=<<(f=<<).f.words` is equivalent to `\s0 -> (concatMap f . f . words $ s0) ! s0`:

```hs
            s0 = "The quick brown fox jumps\nover the lazy dog."
      words s0 = ["The","quick","brown","fox","jumps","over","the","lazy","dog."] = s1
          f s1 = ["The","dog.","quick","lazy","brown","the","fox","over","jumps"] = s2
concatMap f s2 = "Tehd.ogqkucilyazbnrwotehfxoorvejsupm"                           = s3
       s3 ! s0 = "Teh d.ogq kucil yaz bnrwo\ntehf xoo rvej supm"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
UΣSze↔mȯUΣSze↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/Tc4uCq1EdtU3JPrIez////H61kaGRsYqqko2RmbgEkLZViAQ)

This doesn't work with a reusable function since a function can only support one type of arguments.